# Why DFA is equivalent to Delayed input DFA

Tags: algorithm, packet, dfa, inspection, network-security

I'm recently reading a paper [Algorithms to Accelerate Multiple Regular Expressions
Matching for Deep Packet Inspection](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.4795&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about Delayed input DFA. 
According to Lemma 1 in the paper, DFA is equivalent to the corresponding Delayed input DFA. But consider a counter example below:
Let f(i, s) denote the transition function, where s is the current state and i is the input character.
DFA:

```
f(a, 1) = 3, f(b,1) = 3, f(c, 1) = 3, f(a, 2) = 3, f(b, 2) = 3
```

The corresponding Delayed input DFA:

```
f(a, 1) = 3, f(b, 1) = 3, f(c, 1) = 3, f(null, 2) = 1 (null means the default transition)
```

Then the original DFA can't match the character c from state 2 while the Delayed input 
DFA can match c by first go to state 1 using the null character and then match c.
Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they're assuming that the transition function of the original DFA is total, by introducing an explicit error state if necessary. Your transition function `f` is undefined for `(c, 2)`.